# What is the ideal charging behavior for a new Retina MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I've called Apple Support a bunch of times, but I got conflicting answers.

To my knowledge, new technology makes it okay to keep the charger plugged in non-stop, but I want to make sure I am properly caring the computer.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Thanks. Do you happen to have any other documentation or references other than that post?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you may have to remove the charger when the battery is at 100%, even though (I don't actually know whether it does) mbp disallowed current input, i'd remove it anyway. 
I hope I answered your question.

Comment: I've seen no reputable source say removing the charger when it's 100% helps. The battery is already topped off and it won't matter much if you leave it then.

Comment: don't leave your Mac plugged in for long periods at a time, say, over a week. The battery needs to exercise, and if it's plugged in for a really long time, it might "atrophy."